# Started backup via RMAN, any way to nohup it?

Tags: oracle, rman

Backup script was failing, so we started new backup manually through RMAN, is there any way to force RMAN to work after i terminate my ssh session? Ctrl+Z in rman unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Do you not want to schedule it, for example in crontab?

Answer (score 0):

Once you start an RMAN operation, the process you started it from is required to stay alive and awake, as that is the session coordinating the other sessions.

You can not exit or put that session in background.

Next time use `nohup` or even better, my personal favorite: `screen`.